# How to improve the neural art algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I have been playing around the algorithm with tensorflow in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06576).
I tried to convert a photo to a Chinese ink and wash painring, but I got some strange patterns in the output picture(those in the top left corner).
[image]
I totally followed the algorithm in the paper except that I add another loss term for total variation denoising.
I have some confusions about this:

1. In the paper it used the 16-layer vgg net. I am going to try some
   other networks, such as googlenet or alexnet. But I was wondering
   whether it would avoid these patterns if I use some other networks.
2. In the paper, it used the gram matrix to represent the style
   loss. But I don't know the reason here. I was also wondering if
   there's any other way to stand for the style loss.
3. Since I have used total variation denoising here, and the
   result is not satisfactory. I was wondering if there're some other
   ways of denoising to avoid these patterns.

(I'm sorry that I can't
upload my content input image because I don't have enough reputation
in stack overflow as a new user. If you're interested, you can
search the google image with"Shanghai Jiaotong university" and find
the original image there.)

Comment: I think that is an impressive result, but I have only seen other outputs of the style transfer work, not studied it. If you link the original photo and style source in a comment here, I will edit them into the question for you (I'm not going to go searching for matches). I think the both source images are important in case they have some noise element that contributes to the patterns that you do not want.

Comment: original photo(the second photo in the link):  http://m.v4.cc/News-1500016.html  style source:http://www.ivsky.com/tupian/shuimo_fengjing_v3890/pic_119419.html  Thank you.@NeilSlater